# MS Access setting max length of a string in a query

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, maxlength

I'm having an issue setting the max length of a *username* field that is the result of a query. The query takes an employees *first* name's letter, their *last* name and combines them.

ie, Bob Smithson = bsmith or Danny Charlesworth = dcharl

I understand that people have long names and to limit the username to something like 6 or 7 characters would make logins less tedious.

Here's my query code:

```
Username: LCase(Left([first],1) & [last])
```

Pretty simple, but I cannot find any *maxlen* or *left == 7* for example. I could do a work around and do a for loop and knock off a letter on the right until it matches 7, but there must be a faster way to do this. The query populates the form in real time and makes it look nice. Also I don't know how to edit the field of a query textbox since the form would update on load.

Thanks

Comment: I'd use `left`... which you're already using to shorten the first name

Comment: Oh duh, I underestimated left's uses

Comment: mid ? know https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/mid-statement

Answer (score 0):

Username: LCase(Left([first],1) & Left([last],5))

with regards to this question "Also I don't know how to edit the field of a query textbox since the form would update on load."

Go to query design,
under the field name, do the following

1. Delete the field name
2. write "New field name:LCase(Left([first],1) & Left([last],5))"

in your case, the new field name will be user name.